# Passing and assigning pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pointer-to-pointer

I'm having trouble on how to assign information while using a pointer.

I can't assign any values in the `readName` function. and can you check if I malloc the structs correctly?
OR
Is there another way to do this without changing the struck and the function parameter?

```
typedef struct name
{ 
    char info[];
    int number;
    //some more codes
} name;

typedef struct Data
{
    name ** n;
    //some more codes
} Data;


int readName(FILE *const fp, name **const names)
{
    (*names)->number = 1; // no idea what to put here to store
    strcat ((*names)->info, "aBC");
    //codes
}

int read(FILE *const fp, Data *const data)
{
    data->n = malloc(sizeof(name*)*1);   // am I mallocing correctly?
    data->n[0]=malloc(sizeof(name));
    i = readName(fp, &data->n[Data->n]);
    //codes
}

int main ()
{
    Data * d;
    d = malloc (sizeof (Data));
    i = read(fp, d);  //assume fp is decleared
    //codes that usses the struct
}
```

Comment: You need to declare a size for `info[]`.

Comment: `strcat()` on `info` without apparent `\0` initialization of `info`.

Comment: "double pointer" could mean a pointer to a `double` or a pointer-to-pointer-to-something. By convention it's generally understood to mean the former. If that isn't what you intended, please edit your question to rephrase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  data->n = malloc(sizeof(name*)*1);   // am I mallocing correctly?
  data->n[0]=malloc(sizeof(name));
```

you have only allocated space for 1 pointer `data->n = malloc(sizeof(name*)*1);` therefore you have **1** pointer to a name struct.

```
i = readName(fp, &data->n[filep->ncards]);
```

but then you do the above, you can only do `&data->n[0]` you cannot do `&data->[1]` or higher subscripts. if you want more than 1 pointer to pointer to name, you must allocate space for the pointer and then make the pointer point to some valid memory.

try this

```
data->n = malloc((struct name*)how many pointers you want); 
for(int i =0;i<how many pointers you want;i++)
data->n[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct name));
```

from you code since its not complete, I think ncards = how many pointers you want.

```
int readName(FILE *const fp, name **const names)
try
int readName(FILE *const fp, name ** names)
```

you wont be able to change data through a const** pointer, remove the const and try again

Comment: Yes, I edited ncards to Data->n since that is how many pointers I need.
I'm allocated 1 pointer because I only needed one right now, and planed to realloc later. 
Can you show me what I should have in the `readName` function?
(*names)->number = 1; //this is not working for me

Comment: @user3335341 not sure what exactly your intentions are in the read name function, if you provide a sample code that compiles maybe I can have a look and check the errors.

Comment: @user3335341 change the name** const names to name** names this might be the problem.

Comment: I'm given a function and can not do anything with the parameters. 
in the `readName` function I'm suppose to read names from file input and store it into the `name.info`. `name.number` is the number of names in the file